# Glyphicons in Bootstrap 3 aren't appearing

Tags: icons, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 and I have entered the following code for gylphicons

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
        <i class="icon-cog icon-large" >  </i>
        <h2>Our Solutions</h2>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
```

but no icon appears.

am I missing something? does it have to be enabled somewhere? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap 3 fonts folder in the same directory as your bootstrap css and js folders?

Comment: I am using a barebones theme (roots) - the icons are in a fonts folder in the assets folder in themes root, ie theme/assets/fonts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using [bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) the code is

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
```

also, look if the glyphicons are in your project, now (different to bootstrap 2) the glyphicons are now a font, located in /fonts